# Flutter Web : Create UI with mobile app size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a Flutter app and it is work fine in android , iOS and Web . But in web it has full screen width that is very ugly . How can I create UI as like as mobile version for web ?

Comment: This might help you out https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a

Comment: @NishuthanS Thank you . this class give the screen size and I can tell to flutter that I want x% of whole screen width . But I want tell to flutter that if the screen is for a mobile device you can show image with 100% of screen width and if it is web version and run in chrome in desktop OS you must use 50% of screen width

Comment: @NishuthanS is it possible to get a "friendly link" to that article? The one you posted is behind a paywall

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @nishuthan-s I solved my problem with KisWeb and Container

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    width: kIsWeb ? 400.0 : double.infinity,
    child: ListView.builder(...)
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer [This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a) to effectively scale UI according to different screen sizes.

To determine if the user is using the browser use `kIsWeb`

Ex:

```
Image.network('Exampleurl.com',height:kIsWeb?webHeight:mobileHeight);
```

But I personally use this class for dynamic resizing instead of the one mentioned above both are similar but the one given below has 2 functions to get width and height with respect to the aspect ratio.

**Screensize.dart**

```
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate width as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}

}
```

Example:

```
Image.network('Exampleurl.com',height:getProportionateScreenHeight(150));
```

or

```
Image.network('Exampleurl.com',height:(kIsWeb)?getProportionateScreenHeight(250):getProportionateScreenHeight(100));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . How can I set whole screen width in web with this ?

Comment: @mmsh You can get the full-screen width with ```SizeConfig.screenWidth``` This will return the full-screen width of the device.

Comment: thanx . but how getting the size can help me ? I exactly want to tell to flutter if the app run in browser in desktop or laptop you must show the app width mobile width

Comment: ```kIsWeb``` (value is true if web browser) is a global variable that tells if the user is using it in the browser or another platform.

Comment: Yes I understand KIsWeb . But witch widget should I use that if kIsWeb is true the widget width can customize whole screen width ?